# phpize not a directory -- heroku zlib install

Tags: php, heroku

I'm trying to allow my heroku wordpress install to be able to write files heroku. To do this, I'm trying to install zlib. Fortunately, I got referred to a section of the tutorial on this, but I'm having some trouble. The tutorial tells me to run the following in heroku bash :

```
heroku run bash

export PS1="\u@\h \w> "

mkdir tmp

cd tmp

git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git -b PHP-5.3

cd php-src

cd ext/zlib  

/app/php/bin/phpize

./configure –with-php-config=/app/php/bin/php-config

make 

cd modules

scp zlib.so user@host:~/destination

exit
```

I'm stuck at

```
cd ext/zlib     

/app/php/bin/phpize

./configure –with-php-config=/app/php/bin/php-config
```

I'm presuming he means to cd to `/ext/zlib/app/php/bin/phpize`

I can cd all the way to /bin, but I can't seem to cd to phpize. if I type "dir", I do see something called phpize in the terminal.

What would I need to run to execute the command above? Knowing that I'm currently on the directory `/ext/zlib/app/php/bin`

Comment: If you look at the `ext/zlib` directory, you'll find a file named `config0.m4`. Rename it to `config.m4` and then run `/app/php/bin/phpize`.

Comment: when I write scp zlib.so user@host:~/destination , I am getting error. How can I copy that into my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpize is a utility program. Install php-devel

Comment: I see. Sorry for the newbie question, but how would I install php-devel?

Comment: This depends on the OS you have. Google package manager the system you have.

Comment: Hey Scoota, since I'm running a heroku bash, this means that the package manager isn't installed on heroku right? I tried running install php-devel, but it said missing destination file after opening php-devel. Do you know what I would to install it on there?